# yeoman grunt build error with parsing template

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-usemin

I created webapp using yeoman generator. On fresh app I run: `grunt build --verbose` and there is this error:

```
Files: app/index.html -> html
Options: dest="dist"
Going through app/index.html to update the config
Looking for build script HTML comment blocks
Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (Unexpected token )). Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.0.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-babel": "^6.0.0",
    "grunt-browser-sync": "^2.1.2",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.12.2",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-eslint": "^17.0.0",
    "grunt-filerev": "^2.2.0",
    "grunt-mocha": "^0.4.12",
    "grunt-newer": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-postcss": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-sass": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": "^2.0.1",
    "grunt-usemin": "^3.0.0",
    "grunt-wiredep": "^2.0.0",
    "jit-grunt": "^0.9.1",
    "time-grunt": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "env": {
      "node": true,
      "browser": true,
      "es6": true,
      "jquery": true,
      "mocha": true
    },
    "rules": {
      "quotes": [
        2,
        "single"
      ],
      "indent": [
        2,
        2
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me? What I did before is just apdate to newset npm version and yeoman too...

EDIT

Here is index.html file, I tried also very basic html with only html head and body tags.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test2</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I assume that error occurs in index.html. Could you add a code of this file?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `imagemin` task for extra `%`'s.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35090387/5858382

Comment: Yes, it's a bug which they've fixed very recently: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/commit/380823e82377cc3302e708eeedd2af1b973287c8